# android phone moving

Tags: android, gps

Right now I am getting a GPS location every 10 minutes from my android phone via:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 600000, this);
```

When the phone is moving, I'd like to receive location updates more frequently.

To this problem I have 2 questions:

- How can I find out if the phone is moving (I can do it by checking
  distances between 2 location fixes, but there should be a faster
  way?)
- Is there a call to a method where I can change the minTime parameter
  (the 3rd one: 600000) on the fly?

Comment: you cannot know that the phone is moving if you are not checking its location (unless you consider shaking-moving, in which case the accelerator does that)

Comment: you could try to see if the connected cell changes, but that is not very reliable

Comment: if you are moving fast try to use GYROSCOPE :)

Comment: Hmmm... guess I have no choice but to calc. difference between 2 locations

Comment: Any Idea on the second question?

Answer (score 0):

I think I can Suggest you in this 
Store the Coordinates Last Visited in Your Local Database if you dont get the latest coordinates fetch out out the coordinates  saved in your database along with the message

```
"Person is moving "--
I know This is not your Answer But it can be a guess that mobile is moving
```

Comment: I agree on storing the coordinates last visited. The other part I don't agree with. If I don't get the last coordinates, it doesn't mean the person is moving

Comment: Yea thats why i have written that you can make a guess
i am sorry for that